# How to make auto start application in blackberry

Tags: blackberry

I don't know how make my application as auto start application.That is my expectation is,After simulator loads it should not open normal main screen which consist of contacts icon,message icons. it should directly run my application.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try project->properties->BlackBerry Project Properties->Application tab->Auto-run on startup

See [BlackBerryForums.com - Running a Java App on Startup](http://www.blackberryforums.com/developer-forum/1255-running-java-app-startup.html)

Answer (score 1):

Here's another link related to the subject matter:

http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800451/800660/How_To_-_Create_an_auto-start_MIDlet.html?nodeid=1408081&vernum=0

However, it sounds like you might be expecting the simulator to work like other manufacturer simulators where the application you are working on automatically boots when the simulator starts.  This doesn't happen with the BlackBerry simulator, but your app should be located in the Download folder.

Answer (score 0):

To add to Max Gontar's answer, make sure that this same name is stored in the property:

- BlackBerry Project Properties -> Build tab -> Output file name

And then the Debug Configuration needs to be updated with this same Output file name. By default, the debug configuration inserts the name of the project, which is not always the same as this output name.

That's the part that got me caught out (project name was copied from a different project).

So it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Through XML descriptor of any blackberry application one can set checked on auto-run on start up and select start up tier for your application.