# make application alive even after battery is pulled out and then insert and switch on handheld device

Tags: blackberry

i want to make application is always run in background even when we pulled out the battry,
i have make the application which goes to background,even after getting shut down the device  and then restart the device,my application is running in background.
but after removing the battry and then insert the battry and restart the device it will not in background.
plz tell me it could be possible or not,
of yes then how can i do that..

Comment: Have you configured your application to auto-start on boot?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078654/how-to-make-auto-start-application-in-blackberry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a recent dev blog post that steps you through the process:

http://devblog.blackberry.com/2010/06/running-in-the-background-part-2/

You may also want to look at the samples that are included with the JDK (there is an autostart sample) and at the multiple forum posts and guides to this solution on the official RIM site andelsewhere.

As an aside: I see you continue your trend of not accepting answers to any questions; this will soon make it difficult to get future answers.