# how to invoke a method on a particular date, blackberry?

Tags: blackberry, java-me, methods, scheduled-tasks, scheduling

I'm creating an blackberry application. i want to invoke a method on a particular date.. i.e scheduling the process.

Answer (score 1):

Just use method `schedule(TimerTask task, Date time)` for [Timer](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.0.2api/java/util/Timer.html) object in your application: .

Comment: what will happen, on restarting the OS??!

Comment: is there any way to do this by adding alarm or event, but its should not shown in the alarm or event list in blackberry??

Comment: I think it's a good idea to make you application with timer run in background after starting it. How to make auto start application in blackberry you may read here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078654/how-to-make-auto-start-application-in-blackberry