# detect when blackberry App is Auto-started at boot up time vs started by user

Tags: blackberry, startup, launch

I want to have my app automatically run at start time in order to register with the HttpFilterRegistry.  I know [how to make my app auto-start](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1078654/how-to-make-auto-start-application-in-blackberry) but what I'm really after is differentiating between when the sytem starts the app and when the user starts the app.  If the user is starting the app, I want to just show the GUI.  If it's the system, I want to just register the HTTP filters.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you create your Alternate Entry Point, specify an "Application argument". When the app launches you can do this in your main() method

```
//Autostart
if( args != null && args.length > 0 && args[0].equals("the_application_argument")) {
    //register HTTP filters
}

//User start
else{
    //launch the GUI
}
```

Comment: ok so that works, but when I try to launch my app from the HTTP filter, its as if the app is running inside the browser in that, if I exit the app, and go into the browswer, it shows my App.  what is the proper way to launch an app from a web browser?

Comment: Take a look at the CHAPIDemo included with the samples, should get you going in the right direction

Answer (score 0):

there is a function called inStartup() in application Manager class 
Determines if the device is in the process of starting up. so you can check on it.
i think its better than create new entry point and pass an arguments to main

Comment: inStartup() is to ensure that an application launched on start up is well behaved. From the API it: "Determines if the device is in the process of starting up. During startup, all threads must quiesce in order for the startup process to move on to the next startup tier." Since the execution is non-deterministic you can not garuntee that when an applicatin calls inStartup() the system will still be in the start up phase. This is why the recommended way of differentiating between autostart and userstart is as jprofitt said in his answer.